# Flash movie not respecting negative margin in container HTML

Tags: html, css, flash

I have to place a flash movie into an existing layout. It is replacing placeholder image of the same size. The DIV holding the image has a negative top margin. When the flash movie is placed in the same spot there is a gap at the top of the DIV equal to the amount of negative margin. I cannot seem to get the movie to move to the top of the DIV (FF3).

Is there an issue with Flash and negative margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the method you're using to embed the flash.

Have you tried the following on your DIV instead of the negative margin?

```
DIV {
   position: relative;
   top: -10px;
   width: (same as flash);
   height: (same as flash);
}
```